# Unity 2020 - 2D Game, Getting an error that my object couldn't be set to an instance of an object while working with Raycasts

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm currently working on a 2D game on Unity with grid-based movement.
I've run into a problem with the raycasting system (which I plan to use to detect what's in the tile the player is moving to).

My entire player code is split up between groups which are all connected to the parent script known as "playerScript".

I'm getting the errors from the two scripts "PlayerCollisionScript" & "PlayerMovementScript"
**PlayerCollisionScript** looks like this

```cs
using UnityEngine;
public class PlayerCollisionScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField]
    internal PlayerScript playerScript;

    internal void IfPlayerWalkWall()
    {
        RaycastHit2D hit = Physics2D.Raycast(transform.position, transform.TransformDirection(playerScript.direction), 1f);
        if (hit.collider.name == "Walls")
        {
            Debug.Log("Walk wall");
        }
    }

}
```

and **PlayerMovementScript**

```cs
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerMovementScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField]
    internal PlayerScript playerScript;

    private void Update()
    {
        // What happens when the player moves
        if ((playerScript.moveUp == true) && !playerScript.isPlayerMoving)
        {
            playerScript.direction = Vector2.up;
            playerScript.collisionScript.IfPlayerWalkWall();
            if (playerScript.hitWall == false)
            {
                StartCoroutine(MovePlayer(playerScript.direction));
            }
            playerScript.hitWall = false;
        }
    }
```

I keep getting off it the error [Error Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9BUac.png)

I've so far have attempted moving the entire Raycast code into the MovementScript but I still got the same error, **this error occurs as long as I type in the CollisionScript something to `hit`** for example `hit.collider.name` will get this error, `hit` itself will work just fine.

Thanks for anyone willing to help ^^

Comment: Check if the 'Playerscript' is attached in the editor. Also share which exact line is line 16 where the error occurs

Comment: Can you log the value of hit.collider in the PlayerCollisionScript? It might be possible the name field just doesn't exist.

Comment: @rustyBucketBay it is attached to all the scripts

Comment: @DanielGeyfman did what you said it returned `Walls(UnityEngine.TilemapCollider2D)`

Comment: Have you tried hit.collider.gameObject.name if you want to get the name of the gameObject? If you want to get the tag, try hit.collider.gameObject.tag.

Comment: @DanielGeyfman I've attempted it now however it sadly isn't working, if I put it into `Debug.Log(hit.collider.gameObject.name.ToString() == "Walls"` it will return true however if I put it into the `if ()` statement it will give the error

Comment: So the problem is the if statement... maybe an error in the code inside the if loop? Can you try debugging a few major points in the code to see where it went wrong?

Comment: @DanielGeyfman Found the issue its in 
```csharp
RaycastHit2D hit = Physics2D.Raycast(transform.position, transform.TransformDirection(playerScript.direction), 1f);
```
Pretty much the value in the end (The max distance causes the error), I've tried to add a if statement if the value is null but couldn't get it to work, I guess I'll try the masking feature instant of giving it a max distance then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please refer to the [API](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics2D.Raycast.html):

> "This function returns a RaycastHit2D object with a reference to the collider that is hit by the ray (**the collider property of the result will be NULL if nothing was hit**)."

Especially since you limit the maximum distance of the raycast to `1` unit it is not unlikely that it does hit nothing.

Your script should be checking that before trying to access `hit.collider.name`

```c#
RaycastHit2D hit = Physics2D.Raycast(transform.position, transform.TransformDirection(playerScript.direction), 1f);   
if (hit.collider && hit.collider.name.Equals("Walls"))
{
    Debug.Log("Walk wall");
}
```